# Como pasar un objeto en una prop a un componente de vista, a través del Router

Tags: router, vue3, props

> Mi gran duda es respecto al pasaje de props. Cuando yo llamo a un componente dentro de otro, le puedo pasar props como si se trataran de atributos HTML. Pero si el componente al que le voy a pasar dicha prop es un componente de vista (es decir, no lo llamo como `<MiComponente :prop="miProp" />`, sino haciendo uso del `router`) no se como se pasaría una prop en este caso. Esto es lo que intenté y no funciona:

Tengo una ruta que usa el componente `Character.vue`

```
  {
    path: '/character/:character',
    name: 'Character',
    props: true,
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "character" */ '../views/Character.vue')
  }
```

Y en otro componente `Card.vue`, (en el cual tengo un objeto en `prop.character`) tengo una función que hace lo siguiente:

```
  router.push({
    name: "Character",
    params: {
      character: { ...props.character },
    },
  });
```

Mi intención es que al cargarse la ruta de nombre `Character`, tenga en sus `props` el valor que viene del componente `Card.vue` (props.character)

Para ello, en el componente de vista `Character.vue` tengo

```
 props: {
    character: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
```

> Al ejecutar la función de `Card.vue`, soy redirigido a una ruta `http://localhost:8080/#/character/[object%20Object]`, es decir, estoy pasando un string en lugar de un objeto. Alguien me podría decir cual es el camino correcto para recibir el objeto en la vista `Character.vue`? Muchas gracias

Comment: Che, yo tengo hecho algo similar, pero el objeto lo obtengo en Data a partir de la info dentro de router. Ejemplo:       yourParam: this.$route.params.yourParam

Comment: @FrancoBerardi No te seguí bien la respuesta, entiendo que en lugar de hacer uso de la composition API + useRoute, vas por la funcion data a obtener ``this.$route.params.etc``. Yo a eso logro recibirlo, el problema es que no estoy recibiendo el objeto que mando cuando llamo a router.push, sino que estoy recibiendo un string ``"[Object Object]"``. No se si tengo un error haciendo router.push, en el router, o en ambos, pero el objeto que intento enviar, no lo recibo en mi componente de vista (Terminé resolviendo con Vuex, pero me surgió esta duda y por eso realicé la pregunta)

Comment: mmm creo que tu problema es que especifiques en la ruta path: '/character/:character', por eso intenta mandarlo por la url y te lo pasa a string. Tal vez puedes pasarle solo el id? /character/:characterId y el resto del obejto como lo estas haciendo. Intento hacerme un hueco en la semana para mandarte un ejemplo si no te anda..

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-router-playground-forked-x2yfhn?file=/src/pages/Main.vue te dejo un ejemplo cortito. Fijate la page WithProps.vue .. ahi juega con la prop y el data para que puedas usar la prop cuando necesites y la route caso contrario. El ejemplo AsString funciona de todas formas pero le hace el stringify en la url (horrible) asi que me quedo con la opcion 1 (asObject). De todas formas al pasar el objeto asi y redirigir, si el usuario recarga la pantalla (o se guarda la URL) no va a poder usarla. Estaría bueno controlar si la data no está y cargarla

Comment: @FrancoBerardi te agradezco, acabo de probarlo y funciona perfecto. La unica cosita es que usas Vue 2 y Router 3, yo uso Vue 3 y Router 4, voy a tratar de adaptarlo cuando salga de laburar, pero exactamente eso que hiciste es lo que necesito. Muchas gracias!

Comment: sip! por eso no lo puse como respuesta. Espero lo puedas adapatar. Me cambié a React y no usé nunca vue3 :)

Comment: Una cosa que he visto bastante es convertir el objeto a un string en base64, así la URL es más "amigable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres enviar un parametro por URL no puedes enviar un objetos a menos que lo conviertas en un string en base64.

Si por el contrario no necesita enviarlo por url solo haga esto:

```
 router.push({
    name: "Character",
    params: props.character   
  });
```

Router

```
 {
    path: '/character' //quitar /:character,
    name: 'Character',
    props: true,
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "character" */ '../views/Character.vue')
  }
```

Sin embargo esto solo le servira si objeto `props.character` no contiene ningun objeto dentro ya que si intenta enviar:

```
  {
    id: '3', 
    admin: true, 
    info:{ name: 'hola' }
  }
```

Recibira en la vista

```
 {
    id: '3', 
    admin: true, 
    info:"[Object Object]"

  }
```

Comment: Buenas! Lo de que no serializa el  objeto interno, no es así. Funciona OK tanto para el primer nivel como para el N (lo podes ver en el link que está en los comments). Estoy de acuerdo con lo de base64, pero habría que tener cuidado de cuando es una buena decisión.

Comment: En el ejemplo de de los comentarios se esta utilizando Vue 2.  Parece que algo cambio en Vue 3.